# Creating an xssf workbook from an uploaded .xlsx(2007 Excel file)

Tags: java, apache-poi

In the code the client uploads a standard .xlsx file through struts.

In the action we take the file using

```
FormFile myfile = ABCForm.getTheFile();
```

My query is how would I create a XSSFWorkbook out of this file.

I also have a parallel process for accessing 2003 excel file this way

```
FormFile myfile = ABCForm.getTheFile();
byte[] fileData = myFile.getFileData();
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);

in the Helper class

POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(byteArrayInputStream);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

and then further processing of the workbook.

I would like to know how to create a XSSFWorkbook as I have created the HSSFWorkbook above.

I have all the ooxml and related jars in the classpath and lib folder.

XSSFWorkbook cannot be created from byteArrayInputStream. [Apache XSSF Workbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) . It can only be created from Inputstream and OPCPackage.

Any ideas/pointers on how to go about further. I will be glad to give further details about any other code snippets that would help.

Answer (score 10):

You can happily create a XSSFWorkbook from an InputStream

One option is to use WorkbookFactory, which auto-detects the appropriate type and returns a HSSFWorkbook or XSSFWorkbook for you:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```

Otherwise, you can create a XSSFWorkbook from a stream like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(inputStream));
```

However, be aware that opening a XSSFWorkbook from a File needs less memory than from a Stream - with a Stream the whole file will need to be buffered into memory

Comment: Good explanation. Is there any way to tell what kind of file you're working with after creating the workbook with the workbook factory? I only saw create methods in that Factory class.

Comment: Just use `instanceof` to test if it's a HSSFWorkbook or XSSFWorkbook, if you really need to know which it is

Comment: This is an issue because App Engine has a limited amount of memory and loading the entire input stream into memory is causing java.lang.outofmemory issues for me unfortunately. Need to figure out a way to buffer while reading from an input stream since there is no local file structure in the app engine world.

Comment: @advocate You'd like need to use the Event Model / Event User Model to keep your memory footprint down then, but that should then be a brand new question

Comment: Well if there's a work around that would be preferred as I wrote the code and tested only locally before deploying to app engine. I'd rather not have to do an entire rewrite of my parser =\ I was hoping there might be a java conversion workaround from inputstream to some kind of buffered or file input stream or maybe some Apache API calls to buffer the input somehow.